# Most efficient algorithm to compress folder of files

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a folder of files and would like to losslessly compress it as efficiently as possible.

The files are very similar to one another in that the main payload is exactly the same but a variable sized header and footer may differ quite a bit between files.

I need to be able to access any of the files very quickly as well as add additional files very quickly (not have to decompress the entire folder just to add the file to recompress again). Deletion from the folder is not very common.

Algorithmic suggestions are fine though I would prefer to just be able to use some existing library/program for this task.

Comment: There are lots of existing libraries, but it kind of depends on what language and platform you're using.  Is this for C, C++, Python, .NET, PHP ... ?

Comment: @Jim Mischel, aren't the same algorithms available for pretty much all languages? It's not like there is a magical Python compression algorithm that only works in Python.  :-)

Comment: @Samuel Neff: Yes, algorithms are available for any language. But the OP mentioned a preference for existing libraries/programs. Some implementations would be very difficult or impossible to call from a particular language/environment. I don't think he'd want me to recommend a Python library for Linux when he's writing a C++ program on Windows. Thus the request for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case since you have specific knowledge of the files, a custom solution would work best.  Store the static main payload only once and then store the headers and footers separately.  For example, say you have 3 files:

```
1.dat
2.dat
3.dat
```

Store them in the compressed file as:

```
payload.dat
1.header.dat
1.footer.dat
2.header.dat
2.footer.dat
3.header.dat
3.footer.dat
```

As far as adding files, Zip and 7zip support adding new files to an existing archive so you can use either and just append new files as needed.  Personally I would recommend 7zip as I've found in most situation it provides much better compression ratios but it varies a lot depending on the exact content.

Comment: 'Not invented here': zip or 7zip will handle the repeated portions of the files just as well as this suggestion, for a much simpler and more maintainable whole solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime back it was **7zip**, not sure if something new has been made.

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of redundant data, most standard compression software should produce very satisfactory results. DO NOT use the standard Windows .zip generator for this, because it compresses each file separately. 7zip or Gzip will work great for this, though.

Comment: But if you don't compress each file separately, then it's much more expensive to get a single file out of the archive, or to add a new file. The original specification was to be able to do both of those very quickly.